# base depending on the parameter

Tags: linear-algebra

Need help
$V = \text{lin}((1,1,3,2),(4,5,2,5),(2,3,-4,1),(1,2,-5,5))$

a)Find base and $ dimV$

b)For which $ t \in \mathbb{R}$, exist base $\alpha1, \alpha2, \alpha3, \alpha4 \in \mathbb{R}^4$
such $\alpha1 \in \mathbb{V}, \alpha1 + 2\alpha3 \in \mathbb{V}$ and vector $\beta = (1,1,3,3)$ in the base has coordinate $ (0,t,1,0)$? For each $t$ give an exepmle.

a) base is$ (1,1,3,2),(4,5,2,5),(1,2,-5,5) $ and $dimV=3$ right?

b) $\beta \notin V$

$\beta = t\alpha2 + \alpha3$

Comment: @Babak Sorouh there was mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a if you set a matrix, say A, whose rows are the vectors in $V$ and then find the corresponding *Reduced Row Echelon Form*, you will have: $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 3 & 2\\
  4 & 5 & 2 & 5\\
  2&3 &-4 &1\\
  1&2 &-5 &5
\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & -34\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 27\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 3\\
  0&0 &0 &0
\end{pmatrix} $$ This means that the vectors is linearly dependent and the forth vector (as you see in the forth row of the matrix $A$), is a linear combinations of three other vectors. So if $V=\langle v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\rangle$, then $dim(V)=3$. So your attempts for finding a basis is true in $a$.

Comment: sorry in V is $(4,5,2,5)$ not $(1,-1,1,1)$

Comment: Too bad the problem got edited...Nice work for the original post! +1

Comment: could someone help me now?